# Change Eventlistener on file input doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, file, addeventlistener

I am currently working on a web application and I have a file input field where the user can upload images. I´d like to make sure that really just images get uploaded via javascript. Anyhow I can´t get the eventlistener to work... You can find the relevant Code snippets underneath:

```js
"use strict";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init() {
    document.getElementById("reset").addEventListener("click", setBack);
    document.getElementById("anlegen").addEventListener("click", anlegen);
    document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", test);
}

//Check Image Funktion von https://dev.to/faddalibrahim/filtering-and-validating-file-uploads-with-javascript-327p
function test {
    alert("test");
}
```

```html
<div class="col-4">  
  <label for="file">Bild</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" required>
</div>
```

Comment: What part doesn't work? What is it currently doing? What should it do?

Comment: Is it perhaps just a typo when copying, or function `test{}` is missing `()`? It should be `function test() {//body}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `()` in the function declaration of `test`, and there were a couple of `document.getElementById`'s for non-existent html elements with non-existent functions.

See below, it works perfectly fine.

```js
"use strict";
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

function init() {
    document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", test);
}

//Check Image Funktion von https://dev.to/faddalibrahim/filtering-and-validating-file-uploads-with-javascript-327p
function test() {
    alert("test");
}
```

```html
<div class="col-4">  
  <label for="file">Bild</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept="image/*" required>
</div>
```

Comment: So it was a typo?

Comment: I assume so because it works fine when you fix them

Comment: May you flag the question as a typo then?

Comment: I already flagged it

Comment: @KingRaidi always post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - meaning with all the elements - such that people helping you don't get caught up fixing problems that don't actually exist :)